# Check Column/Key Exists?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am running x-cart 4.23 and upgrading to 4.4 so I need to upgrade the database.

Here is the error.

`SQL error #1091 : Can't DROP 'PRIMARY'; check that column/key exists`
`SQL query: ALTER TABLE xcart_customers DROP PRIMARY KEY`

The original error was this....

`SQL error #1075 : Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key`

`SQL query: ALTER TABLE xcart_customers DROP PRIMARY KEY`

When I cleared that I ran into that and have no idea where to start.

Comment: how is this programming related?

Comment: i wanted to answer on this question @Community then i noticed the question was almost a decade old..

Answer (score 1):

This error means that you are trying to delete a key which is being used by another table.

e.g. consider tblMovies and tblActors, movies contain one or more actors and you can't delete delete the tblActors entries (or drop PK) until you delete the Movies featuring those actors.

Then the actors won't be linked so you can delete them.

Comment: Thank you.  I guess since this is an upgrade I should wait before making any changes to my database.

Comment: I do have one further question... For my own interest is their of knowing which key is being used in another table.

Comment: I'm not sure how the upgrade script works for xcart, but make sure to backup the DB entries (to insert statements), then empty it, upgrade it, and run the backup file to re-insert the data.  Also you may read this http://help.qtmsoft.com/index.php?title=X-Cart:Upgrading

Comment: There are few ways, the simplest is try to delete everything and see what is left, those are the Foreign Key- Primary Key relationships that would prevent it from deleting. Then you can focus on those.

Comment: #1075 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key..   Is this a similar error.  I received it first but stumbled onto a solution...  ALTER TABLE xcart_customers DROP PRIMARY KEY....never seems to work when trying to drop the primary.

Comment: This time you are creating one with various PK i guess, so you need only one, show the build script of that part

Comment: When you say build I assume you mean the upgrade script...no idea WHICH is that part so here is the full upgrade script file... http://www.eliocamacho.com/publicDownloads/     I looked for key words to see if I could find it easily and no luck..  sorry...thank you btw.

Comment: hehe I'm sorry to say that you need to try asking this at superuser.com or other site.  php and sql are very different stuff, you may find the sql within the php. Maybe the solution is very simple but you need to find someone experienced with upgrading xcart.

Comment: Yeah....I was afraid of that.  The truth is even on the xcart forum many questions like this and regarding the upgrades are left unanswered.  I was hoping it was just a sql problem and I could move forward with the upgrade.