# MySQL need to make column NOT UNIQUE. Error Can't DROP 'ColumnName'; check that column/key exists

Tags: mysql

ColumnName is Unique (`UNIQUE KEY ColumnName`).

I just want to make column not unique (must be very simple, but can not understand how).

If in phpMyAdmin check at column name and at bottom click on Unique icon, get `#1062 - Duplicate entry '' for key 'RegistrationNumber'`. OK, see it is because, clicking on icon it `ADD UNIQUE`.

There is Unique icon in Structure within row. But the icon is not click-able.

As in phpMyAdmin did not found how to do it, trying with query.

Based on advices tried `ALTER TABLE TableName DROP INDEX ColumnName`.

Get `1091 Can't DROP 'ColumnName'; check that column/key exists`

Here https://stackoverflow.com/a/4414694/2465936 found `This error means that you are trying to delete a key which is being used by another table.` Possibly the ColumnName is used by another table.

Please advice what need to do to make column not unique.

With `SHOW CREATE TABLE` get

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [Table] => 18_6_TransactionPartners
        [Create Table] => CREATE TABLE `18_6_TransactionPartners` (
       `Number` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
       `CompanyName` char(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
       `RegistrationNumber` char(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
        .......
        PRIMARY KEY (`Number`),
        UNIQUE KEY `Number_2` (`Number`),
        UNIQUE KEY `CompanyName` (`CompanyName`,`RegistrationNumber`),
        KEY `Number` (`Number`)
        ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=444 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
    )

 )
```

**Update**

Based on @Bart Friederichs advice tried `ALTER TABLE 18_6_TransactionPartners DROP INDEX Number` and changed column `RegistrationNumber` not not unique. Do not understand why (possibly had some mess with unique keys). In any case can change to not unique.

Comment: You drop an index by its name, not by column name (indices can have multiple columns)

Comment: Do you want to drop the column or the index? The sql you provide is not valid.

Comment: Could you `DESCRIBE table` ?

Comment: Want to make column not unique. Do not want to drop the column. Just want to change to not unique. Sql wrote, based on advices. What is valid sql?

Comment: @BartFriederichs with `Describe` get `Array ( [0] => Array ( [Field] => RegistrationNumber [Type] => char(255) [Null] => NO [Key] => [Default] => [Extra] => ) )`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably you have a named `INDEX`. By using `SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl` you can find out the names of the indices. Then drop them by name (e.g. some test table):

```
mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE test;
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `entry_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `k` (`entry_id`)
)
```

To drop the index, use this:

```
ALTER TABLE test DROP INDEX k;
```

Your key name is `RegistrationNumber` (as is told by the error message):

```
ALTER TABLE TableName DROP INDEX RegistrationNumber;
```

Comment: Instead of `UNIQUE KEY `k` (`entry_id`)` have `UNIQUE KEY CompanyName (CompanyName,RegistrationNumber)`. Tried `ALTER TABLE 18_6_TransactionPartners DROP INDEX CompanyName`. Get `1091 Can't DROP 'CompanyName'; check that column/key exists`

Comment: If you got `Can't DROP 'CompanyName'; check that column/key exists`, then you probably tried to drop the index twice. The first time it succeeded, the second it gave you this message.

Comment: I copied and pasted both your `CREATE TABLE` and `ALTER TABLE` and it works fine.

Comment: Missing from this answer is how to find the index name: SHOW INDEX TableName

Answer (score 2):

If your column was defined unique using UNIQUE clause, then you can do something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable DROP INDEX constraint_name
```

For dropping the index do this:-

```
ALTER TABLE mytable DROP INDEX index_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to drop the index using the index name, not the column name.