# Can't Drop foreign key in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have had a 1 to many relationship between course and instructor, which I wanted to drop. When I tried to drop the instructorID in course table it told me that. I couldn't drop it as it was a foreign key. Then I decided to drop it like this:

```
ALTER TABLE course DROP FOREIGN KEY instructorID
```

But i get this error :

```
#1091 - Can't DROP 'InstructorID'; check that column/key exists
```

I don't get what this error means. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: You need to drop the child column and then the parent. can you show a schema please.

Comment: You will get help from link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414653/check-column-key-exists

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Please run an `SHOW CREATE TABLE course;` to make sure instructorID is the name of foreign key **constraint**.

Additional:
The error means MySQL searches for a foreign key constraint named "InstructorID" but there is no constraint with such name, maybe this is your column name, but you have to use the constraint name to delete foreign keys.

Answer (score 46):

After you run `SHOW CREATE table course;`
you should find the fk symbol which is commonly like the one bellow:

```
(course_ibfk_1)
```

it may differ according to your mysql version you are using then drop the foreign key using the fk symbol as follow :

```
alter table course drop foreign key course_ibfk_1;
```

Comment: This needs more upvotes than the past several answers I found on SO. I can't believe the syntax is to use the 'generic' CONSTRAINT name instead of the actual foreign key column name. This was very hindering

Comment: @OzzyTheGiant: Marco Roy's answer at the following link explains how to avoid this 'generic' CONSTRAINT: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15530/what-does-ibfk-stand-for-in-mysql

Answer (score 6):

You need to delete the 'foreign key constraint' and the 'key'.

```sql
Alter Table <table name> drop foreign key <constraint_name> 
Alter table <table name> drop key <column name>
```

Comment: Thank you - this was making me scratch my head for a while. I added a foreign key, so I assumed I could just remove it. I was getting errors about random issues, but I couldn't figure out why the index was still in place after I issued the `DROP FOREIGN KEY`. I needed to issue `drop key` too.

Answer (score 3):

If any of you still not able to `DROP` the table. Try this. You can able to see all the details by running this

```
SELECT
    TABLE_NAME,
    COLUMN_NAME,
    CONSTRAINT_NAME,
    REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME,
    REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME = 'ReferenceTableName'; <-- change only this
```

If you want to see just the constrains

```
SELECT
    CONSTRAINT_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME = 'ReferenceTableName';
```

Comment: I dropped the index as well and the constraint key could be then deleted.

Comment: ALTER TABLE `category` DROP INDEX `primaryID`;

Answer (score 2):

To drop a FOREIGN KEY constraint:

MySQL:

```
ALTER TABLE Orders DROP FOREIGN KEY {Constraint/Key_name};
```

For SQL Server / Oracle / MS Access:

```
ALTER TABLE Orders DROP CONSTRAINT {Constraint/Key_name};
```

Answer (score 0):

the reason why you cannot drop InstructorID is because you need to use the name of the constraint of the Foreign key . KevDev specified that you must run 'SHOW CREATE TABLE course' to find the constraint name. after doing so , you can delete the foreign key. BUT wait theres more, the 'key' still stays behind which must get deleted. You can run 'SHOW CREATE TABLE' course to check that the key is still behind. once checking that it is still there then perform what Bobby advised. 'Alter table drop key' in doing so you have fully removed the the foreign key

Comment: the reason why you cannot drop InstructorID is because you need to use the name of the constraint of the Foreign key . KevDev specified that you must run 'SHOW CREATE TABLE course' to find the constraint name. after doing so , you can delete the foreign key. BUT wait theres more, the 'key' still stays behind which must get deleted. You can run 'SHOW CREATE TABLE' course to check that the key is still behind. once checking that it is still there then perform what Bobby advised. 'Alter table drop key' in doing so you have fully removed the the foreign key.

Comment: Ok, this looks more as an answer, though I wonder if this adds anything interesting that is not already there in the answers you mentioned (by kevdev and Bobby).

Answer (score 0):

Can't DROP 'string'; check that column/key exists: ALTER TABLE `accreditor_architectures` DROP `string` error show in terminal when remove column from data base in ruby on rails