# Dropping tables with foreign key and dropping foreign key

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I have tables with a lot of foreign keys and they mostly come in both ways, which makes it really hard to drop a table. This screenshot shows relations.

I want to drop `match_teams` table. It obviously say that I can't drop it due to foreign key. So I decided to drop foreign keys first with:
`alter table match_teams drop foreign key player_1` however it returns me error. (#1091 - Can't DROP 'player_1'; check that column/key exists )

What is the best way to drop such table and its foreign keys? What is wrong in my SQL statement?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the constraint is called player_1? remember that the column's name is not necessary the same that the contraint's name.

Comment: No. for some reason it was called match_teams_ibfk_6. And `alter table match_teams drop foreign key match_teams_ibfk_6` works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't Drop foreign key in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25079645/cant-drop-foreign-key-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify the name of the foreing key and try deleting again...

The column's name is not necessary the same that the constraint's name.