# Drop foreign key MySQL does not exist

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have a table in MySQL like this (this is returned from using show create table user_org_contacts):

```
CREATE TABLE `user_org_contacts` (
 `user_org_contacts_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `from_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `to_org_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `suggested_vacancy_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `contact_date` datetime NOT NULL,
 `message` text,
 PRIMARY KEY (`user_org_contacts_id`),
 KEY `FK_Reference_53` (`from_user_id`),
 KEY `FK_Reference_54` (`to_org_user_id`),
 KEY `FK_Reference_55` (`suggested_vacancy_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=18 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

I have noticed that my FK_Reference_54 is wrong and points to the wrong table. So I would like to change this one by the correct FK.

This is what I tried:

```
ALTER TABLE `user_org_contacts` 
DROP FOREIGN KEY `FK_Reference_54`;  

ALTER TABLE `user_org_contacts`  
ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_Reference_54` 
    FOREIGN KEY (`to_org_user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`user_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

This produces the following error:

> ## 1091 - Can't DROP 'FK_Reference_54'; check that column/key exists

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't Drop foreign key in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25079645/cant-drop-foreign-key-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are confusing indexes with primary keys.

The keyword KEY is actually showing you indexes while primary keys use the keywords CONSTRAINT ... FOREIGN KEY ...

Example:

```
CONSTRAINT `FK_name` FOREIGN KEY (`current_field_name`)
REFERENCES `external_table_name` (`external_field_name`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

So in your case, if you want to remove your INDEX you just need to call this query

```
ALTER TABLE `user_org_contacts` 
DROP INDEX `FK_Reference_54`;
```

Next time I suggest you using some UI for mysql like mysql workbench, with that you would have noticed the issue immediatly.

Answer (score 0):

First Try To remove that column
ALTER TABLE tablename DROP COLUMN columname;
Then:
ALTER TABLE tablename ADD columnname datatype.

Or you can try this Modify option like.
ALTER TABLE tablename MODIFY COLUMN columnname datatype;

Hope This will help you.