# SQL index exists, but drop command tells it is not exists

Tags: mysql

In MySQL the follow query returns a row with my index in the table:

```
SHOW INDEXES FROM `my_table` WHERE Key_name = 'thumbnail'
```

While dropping the index:

```
ALTER TABLE `my_table` DROP INDEX `thumbnail`
```

Returns: `Can’t DROP ‘thumbnail’; check that column/key exists`

Then executing:

```
ALTER TABLE `my_table` ADD INDEX `thumbnail` (`thumbnail`(100))
```

Returns: `Duplicate key name ‘thumbnail’`

My logic looks like this and both Query command runs, but drop index does not dropping the table, so Add index won't be able to create it.

```
$hasIndex = QueryRow("SHOW INDEXES FROM `my_table` WHERE Key_name = 'thumbnail'"));
if ($hasIndex) {
    Query("ALTER TABLE `my_table` DROP INDEX `thumbnail`");
}
Query("ALTER TABLE `my_table` ADD INDEX `thumbnail` (`thumbnail`(100))");
```

I do not see why the drop index command is not working. Do you have any suggestion what should I check?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25079645/cant-drop-foreign-key-in-mysql) help?

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy I do not think that is related. SHOW INDEXES command queries based on the name of the key and not the column name, so I think the key name is fine here(even if the index name is the same as the column in this case).

Comment: Please show us `SHOW CREATE TABLE my_table`.

Answer (score 0):

For drop an index  there is also a specific command  so try a simple

```
DROP INDEX `thumbnail` ON `my_table`
```